# Setting static property as Session for getting unique results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, static, integrity

I have a static property like following:

```
public static List<string> _pr { get; set; }
```

Let's imagine a scenario like this:

1. User 1 logs in and fills the _pr property with 100 string items inside _pr;
2. User 2 logs in at the same time and does the exact same thing as User one, only this time he gets 250 different string results into _pr!

These results are not from DB, but rather from an API;

How do I ensure the integrity and uniqueness of data so that each user gets displayed only the results that he gets, since I declared only 1 static property and I have multiple users adding different items into it...

Can you guys help me out with this?

How would I solve this properly in c#?

Edit: This is how I add the items to the specific list:

```
   foreach (var item in _pr)
                {
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.LoadXml(item);
                    ResultItem rezultat = new ResultItem();
                    ViewBag.jsonobjekat = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc));
                    rezultat.SaleNumber = ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["ReturnedTransactionCountActual"];
                    rezultat.StoreName = ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["Item"]["Seller"]["UserID"];
                    rezultat.Feedback = ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["Item"]["Seller"]["FeedbackScore"];
                    rezultat.SaleEarning = Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["Item"]["SellingStatus"]["CurrentPrice"]["#text"]) * Convert.ToInt32(rezultat.SaleNumber);
                    rezultat.SalePrice = Convert.ToDouble(ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["Item"]["SellingStatus"]["CurrentPrice"]["#text"]);
                    rezultat.Title = ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["Item"]["Title"];
                    rezultat.URL = ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["Item"]["viewItemURL"];
                    rezultat.ID = ViewBag.jsonobjekat["GetItemTransactionsResponse"]["Item"]["ItemID"];
                    lista.Add(rezultat);
                    ViewBag.jsonba = ViewBag.jsonobjekat;
                }
                JArray v = JArray.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lista).ToString());
ViewBag.rezultati = v; // this is the part where I need to have unique results for each user
```

And this is how I display the results :

```
<tbody>
                                    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.rezultati)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><a href="http://ebay.com/usr/@item.StoreName" target="_blank">@item.StoreName</a></td>
                                            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" value="@item.StoreName" data-original-title="Analyze competitor"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i></button></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <b>
                                                    @item.SaleNumber
                                                </b>
                                            </td>
                                            <td><b>@item.Feedback</b></td>

                                        </tr>
                                    }

                                </tbody>
```

Comment: instead of having `string` create a class that also stores the reference of user class and when you want to show items you just check `if(storedReference == userReference)`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary can you show me what you mean by that ?

Comment: I cant. I need to see how you add items into list and how you display them. Also beware List is not thread safe. if you want to add items from different threads to the list at same time either use `lock` or `ConcurrentBag`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I updated my question with how I fill the list and display it... I need to display unique results for ViewBag.rezultati for each user...

Comment: Why would you want to use `static` field for user-specific information? Why are you rejecting using `Session` for that data?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not rejecting anything, I'm just without ideas how to display unique results after the above scenario, and to keep the results unique for each user as they filled that variable ... displayed even after the page refreshes :)